# OData SingleResult is Ambiguous in System.Web.Http

Tags: asp.net-web-api, odata, entity-framework-6.1

I am new to using OData with a Web Api.  I have my models defined from a database first EF 6 method, and have added the OData controller.  The resulting code is erroring out on the following:

```vb
< EnableQuery > _

    Public Function [Get](<FromODataUri> key As Integer) As SingleResult(Of Product)
        Dim result As IQueryable(Of Product) = db.Product.Where(Function(p) p.ID= key)
        Return SingleResult.Create(result)
    End Function
```

The error is on the SingleResult providing the following error: SingleResult is ambiguous in system.web.http.

Any advice on what causes this error? Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you don't have multiple OData NuGets installed. I had 2.1 and 2.2 (for OData v4 support) installed, which gave me the exact same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Return SingleResult(of Product).Create(result)
```

Comment: Thank you, but VS actually underlines the Function call with the error too:

Comment: Public Function [Get](<FromODataUri> key As Integer) As SingleResult(Of Product).  It is saying that it is ambiguous in System.Web.Http. 
I feel like there are 2 things competing in here where it isn't sure how to recognize the SingleResult properly (if that makes sense).  Like maybe I am missing something in the references or web.config?

Comment: For now, I changed the function:
  Public Function [Get](<FromODataUri> key As Integer) As IHttpActionResult
            Return Ok(db.Product.SingleOrDefault(Function(t) t.ID= key))
        End Function

Answer (score 0):

I also faced a similar Exception, `` System.Web.Http.SingleResult`1[MyType]' cannot be converted to type 'MyType' `` while working with OData in ASP.NET Core.

As it's been saying I have been using `SingleResult` from `System.Web.Http`. But the one I wanted was in `Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData.Results` namespace.

So I removed

`using System.Web.Http;` and replaced it with

`using Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData.Results;`

Hope this helps out someone like me.